# HTML email template solution to javascript link in table TD?

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is my current code:

```
<td height="150" style="background: url(bg.jpg); cursor: pointer;" onClick="document.location.href='http://www.youtube.com';">
```

Now obviously with JavaScript this isn't likely to work in email clients (is it?). What is an HTML solution? Thanks in advance! I've tried wrapping link tags around but that doesn't seem to do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the information you have posted (and your comment on @PAM's answer), I think this will solve your problem:

```
<td width="150" style="background-color:rgb(128,128,128); background-image:url('http://www.yoursite.com/yourpicture.gif'); cursor:pointer;">
<a href="http://www.youtube.com">

...Text...

</a>
</td>
```

I've added the `background-color` attribute to the `td` so that users have a fallback if their email client does not display background images. Of course, you should set this to a colour which is similar to the background image.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just style a link to take up the width and height of the td:

```
<td height="150" style="background: url(bg.jpg);"><a href="http://www.youtube.com" style="display:block;height:150px;width:100%;"></a></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just type like that:

```
<td height="150"><a href="http://www.youtube.com"><img src="bg.jpg" /></a></td>
```

Comment: Unfortunately I need it to be a background image because I've text overlaid inside the table's row.